# Does Windows Azure delete VMs that have been switched off?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I turned off several Azure VMs a few months ago, but they are no longer listed or available in my account.
Does anyone know if they auto-delete them if they have been switched off?

Answer (score 1):

No, they wont get deleted and on top of that they will continue to cost you something. If you deallocated them using portal\cli\powershell\rest api, they will only cost whatever their storage costs. if you just did shutdown from inside the VM they will incur full cost.